# Add hyperlink in the visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to add hyperlink in visual studio code.
[image]

For example by clicking Kadane's algorithm I can go to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/   site

The extinction of file I am using is .txt

Is this possible?

Comment: create an extension that understands the format you use and create a `DocumentLinkProvider`, then the text `Kadane's algorithm` can be a Ctrl+Click link

Comment: For txt-file like documents with simple I'd suggest you take a look at markdown, vs code supports it out of the box and it is simple to learn. https://www.markdowntutorial.com/lesson/1/

Comment: Can you clarify what you are planning to do with that txt file? I mean you can put links into just about any file, but whether or not it will be formatter clickable link depends solely on the program that is used to display that text.

For instance: Notepad will never make your link clickable, while notepad++ formats links and makes them clickable automatically.

Answer (score -2):

.txt files do not support hyperlinks. Depending on what your end goal is, you could either write this in basic HTML with an  tag (since you're already in VSCode), or just use Google Docs.

Comment: `.txt` files are basic text files. They can store links. Whether or not those links are displayed as text or a clickable link depends on the program that displays it.